# Wanting a little clarification on closure, scope, and asynchronous

Tags: javascript

I basically copy-pasta this code to asynchronous have a timeout for certain functions, but I am having trouble understanding it.

```
const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
}
/*
  Some stuff
*/
sleep(10000).then(()=>{/*Do something*/});
```

So up above I declared a constant variable labeled ***sleep*** which gets assigned a functional expression that takes in an argument labeled ***milliseconds***.

The functional expression goes on to call function ***Promise*** that will perform a functional expression labeled ***resolve*** asynchronously.

Now this part is where I am getting confused. ***resolve*** functional expression calls ***setTimeout*** which waits in ***milliseconds*** ms then calls ***resolve***. My understanding is that the upper ***resolve*** and the nested one are two different functions, and the nested one is just an empty function named ***resolve***.

Are these two ***resolves*** two different functions that has the same name, or am I fundamentally not understanding what's going on.

The last line is just waiting on the callback from ***sleep*** to do some function.

Another do all these functional expressions diminish the compilers ability to optimize. Specifically I read that setTimeout utilizes eval() which is problematic to optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Thats an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Think of the first `resolve` as a parameter being passed to a function.

It could also be written like this:

```
return new Promise( (resolve) => { 
    return setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds) 
} )
```

Or this: (standard function)

```
return new Promise( function( resolve ) {
    return setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds)
})
```

Comment: So I am correct to assume the two resolves are independent to one another? Ty for your feedback

Comment: No they are the same. The first is a parameter being passed to a function the second is that parameter being called by the setTimeout function.

Comment: Oh I think I understand. So there is an overall anonymous function that accepts the parameter resolve (which is just an empty function) and that gets passed into setTimeout.

Will it be as safe to just do this?
    return new Promise (() => setTimeout(function(){},milliseconds))

Comment: The anonymous function is the callback for Promise, and if you never resolve your Promise then the .then() method will never fire. So the resolve is required.

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is that the upper resolve and the nested one are two
>   different functions

They are the same.

```
const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) =>          // (1) 'resolve' var refers to a function.
    setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))     // (2) 'resolve' here refers to (1) above. In this case you, are invoking 'resolve' function without passing any value.
}

sleep(10000).then(()=>{/*Do something*/}); // (3) after 'resolve' from (2) runs, this 'do something function' receives any value from that and runs.
```

Hope this helps,

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This ES6 snippet:

```
const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
}
```

Translates to ES5:

```
const sleep = function(milliseconds){

  return new Promise(function(resolve){

    return setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds);

  }.bind(this));

}.bind(this);
```

So, there is only *one* `resolve` here, not two.

The `resolve` is the first argument passed to the `Promise` constructor, which happens to be a function, but certainly not a functional expression.

Its "functional expression" comes after that, during the `.then(...)` part.

More on [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).